Multiple network interfaces, one for host and others for segmenting containers/VMs. Can't get container to resolve outside FQDNs
Trying to enable multiple interfaces on my Ubuntu 24.04 server. I would like to isolate certain containers to certain VLANS. LAN & VLANS managed by pfsense.
Network Map
I am using netplan on the host to manage all interfaces except wireguard which is managed by NetworkManager.
I do use ufw on the host also but not sure if any config changes need to be made there.
The main interface that my host uses for internet/LAN access is bridge0 which is part of VLAN10. bridge0 is master of eno1. The bridge was created so that incus containers/VMs could be part of my VLAN10 subnet.
I also have a wireguard server, wg0-server, running on the host that is masqueraded through bridge0.
I recently created a new VLAN in pfsense, VLAN20, and ran an ethernet cable from the managed switch to one of the free ports on the back of the server. The interface name that became active after doing this is enp5so. I created another bridge on the host, bridge2, with enp5so as the slave.
I created another profile in incus to use the VLAN20 subnet with bridge2 as the nic and the container that I assigned the profile to, netTester, properly receives its ip from the VLAN20 subnet. I am able to ping my host (no rules in pfsense preventing this) and I am able to ping 1.1.1.1 & 8.8.8.8 but the container is unable to resolve a fqdn. i.e., I tried traceroute google.com and it says it's unable to resolve google.com. Tried using apt update and that also fails everytime.
I have added 2 routing tables. One for bridge0 named 101 bridge0-route. And one for bridge2 named 101 bridge-route.
Any pointers in the right direction would be great.
My host machine has a total of 7 ethernet ports. One built into the mobo which is what eno1/bridge0 are connected to and a 6 port nic for all other interfaces.
ip a from host
    $ ip a
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    4: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master bridge2 state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 10.0.10.2/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global dynamic enp5s0
           valid_lft 4833sec preferred_lft 4833sec
    8: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master bridge0 state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        altname enp15s0
        inet 192.168.10.2/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic eno1
           valid_lft 4707sec preferred_lft 4707sec
    96: bridge0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.10.3/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global bridge0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe75::232c:18ff:fe99:820/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    97: bridge2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 10.0.20.3/24 brd 10.0.20.255 scope global bridge2
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe99::4157:58ff:fe36:8fe3/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    101: veth9d079b82@if100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master bridge0 state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    103: vethd1ba431a@if102: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master bridge2 state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    104: wg0-server: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/none 
        inet 10.72.19.75/24 scope global wg0-server
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ip route from host
$ ip route
default via 192.168.10.1 dev bridge0 proto static 
10.0.20.0/24 dev bridge2 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.20.3
10.0.20.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.20.2
192.168.10.0/24 dev bridge0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.3
192.168.10.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.2
10.72.19.0/24 dev wg0-server proto kernel scope link src 10.72.19.75 

ip rule from host
$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32764:  from 10.0.20.0/24 lookup bridge2-route proto static
32765:  from 192.168.10.0/24 lookup bridge0-route proto static
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

results from ping and traceroute from within the container. I did not ping the host but that does work as well.
root@netTester:~# ping 1.1.1.1 -c 4
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=15.4 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=15.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=15.1 ms

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.055/16.291/19.016/1.588 ms
root@netTester:~# ping 8.8.8.8 -c 4
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=64.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=62.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=61.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=61.5 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 61.467/62.378/64.404/1.198 ms
root@netTester:~# traceroute google.com
google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `google.com' on position 1 (argc 1)

netplan config on host
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: false
  bridges:
    bridge0:
       interfaces:
         - eno1
       addresses:
         - 192.168.10.3/24
       dhcp4: no
       routes:
         - to: default
           via: 192.168.10.1
         - to: 192.168.10.0/24
           via: 192.168.10.1
           table: 100
       routing-policy:
         - from: 192.168.10.0/24
           table: 100
    bridge2:
       interfaces:
         - enp5s0
       addresses:
         - 10.0.20.3/24
       dhcp4: no
       routes:
         - to: 10.0.20.0/24
           via: 10.0.20.1
           table: 101
       routing-policy:
         - from: 10.0.20.0/24
           table: 101


Resolved.
Improper DNS config in pfsense. All is working as intended now.
